# Android Notepad tutorial: Still "State of the art"?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am going to make my first app for android (no fear it's just a school project and won't be another useless app in the market :>).

So, before starting this task I did some tutorials, one of these (and which I thought would be very useful, because of the sqlite part) was the [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad). While working through it I saw it was originally designed for Android 1.8 or something (certainly it still worked on my android 4.1).

What I'm really wondering now is: 
Is this code still "state of the art" in android programming (especially sqlite, but also the rest :) or is it "deprecated"? If so, can you point me to something newer and better?

Thank you.

Comment: I think its definitely "deprecated". You should be looking at Database helper & loader classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is definitely still the database available by default on every Android device. Also, the basics covered in this tutorial still apply to any Android version. Of course, every new version of the OS also provides new possibilities as to which controls you can use or other new APIs, but for very simple applications, this tutorial is still valid.

Comment: thank you. Though I think you got me wrong with the sqlite, I knew that you still use sqlite, my question was related to HOW sqlite was used (somehow the whole thing didn't look so good for me, with many static constants etc.). But your answer is still what I wanted/needed to know.

Comment: @tenhouse there are lots of constant values (column names etc) in a database and the most efficient way in Java to work with those are `static final` constants.

Comment: Just for your information. I decided to do the databasepart with ORMLite -this is for me much much closer to "state of the art"....

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe one should follow the guidelines and not use ORM tools due to the fact that smartphones are still and should in the future be treated as devices with limited resources (memory, CPU speed). Your users will thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I skimmed the article; most of its content seem to be valid for Android 4.x.
Although I don't think the tutorial mention fragments anywhere : they were introduced with Android 3.0.

I think that an important exercise after this tutorial is to read the fragment documentation; have a look at some samples (like the gallery app) and rewrite the notepad in order to use fragments.
You will have to use the Support Library in order to use fragments if the minimum version of Android supported by your app is inferior to Android 3.0 but I think it is also an interesting exercise.

A little tip : many beginners (and experienced devs also :) ) mistakes come from adding a new element in an app but forgetting to declare it in the manifest.xml.

Comment: thank you. I already read some stuff about fragments and will do an excersie with it.